# jQuery Plugin Tutorial Confusion

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have to be missing something.  The jQuery plugin tutorial found [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring), in the "Namespacing" -> "Plugin Methods" section, there lurks the below plugin declaration.  What I am not getting here is the *scope* of the **methods** variable; I mean, shouldn't **methods** be defined as a var in tooltip?  Once this anonymous function executes, **methods** goes out of scope if I understand correctly because it is defined as a var within a function.  How is it that tooltip references var methods which will be out of scope when tooltip is called?  What am I missing?

```
(function( $ ){

  var methods = {
    init : function( options ) { // THIS },
    show : function( ) { // IS   },
    hide : function( ) { // GOOD },
    update : function( content ) { // !!! }
  };

  $.fn.tooltip = function( method ) {

    // Method calling logic
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
    }    

  };

})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function assigned to `$.fn.tooltip` is a [**closure** *<sup>[Wikipedia]</sup>*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) and therefore has access to all higher scopes.

When the outer function returns, `methods` is not destroyed because the closure still references it.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't go out of scope exactly as your plugin still holds a reference to it. In JS, they are called [closures](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/).

Answer (score 0):

This all works because of closure. The function which `$.fn.tooltip` points to is actually a closure. So it has access to `method` object.